# The CloseDate of Parent record type should always be greater than that of its Child record type

Tags: validation-rule

I have 2 record types called master and child of the same object called opportunity. How do i apply a validation rule to make sure that the close date of master record type is always greater than child record type of the opportunity object.
Can anyone please help me out.

Comment: How are they related to each other? Child has lookup for master opportunity or master detail?

Comment: actually we have created self lookup on opportunity and we are hiding that lookup field  from master record type

Comment: child & master are the name of the record types of opportunity object they r no relation

Comment: Then you will have to create another datetime field on opportunity. Populate this field when child opportunity is closed. Use this field to compare with sysetm.now in your validation rule when parent opportunity is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand the question, you want to prevent the closing of the parent Opportunity with recordtype=`Master` if any of the children Opportunities (each with recordtype=`Child`) have a close date > than the parent (master)'s close date.

**Option 1**

Because the relationship is a lookup relationship, not master-detail, you're going to need to install the [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries (DLRS) package](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) (free) that rolls up the highest child `CloseDate` to a custom field on the parent Opportunity

**Option 2**
If children Oppos can't be deleted, you may be able to use Process Builder to always update the parent Oppo when the child Oppo closes, if the child's close date > the current 'highest' close date on Oppo (same custom field as in Option 1)

**Option 3**
Write a trigger on Opportunity that when it changes, to either signal the parent Oppo to recalculate the custom 'highest' child close date field or to determine the new highest close date and update the parent directly.  Remember to bulkify and handle the case where multiple children of the same parent close in the same batch. Option 3 is essentially rolling your own one-off DLRS

With any of these options, the validation rule becomes straightforward as you are comparing the value of (oparent) `CloseDate` with the (parent) customField `highestChildCloseDate__c`

Answer (score 0):

- For Child Opportunity Record Type you need a lookup field which populated Parent Opportunity.
- Now put a validation rule which compares ParentOpportunity.CloseDate ISGREATER THAN CloseDate.

Comment: i think this is the opposite of OP intent, the rule is parent can't be closed if its close date is not > than all children